# how show text form contact.blade.php in the message in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I makes website by laravel as multi language

and I make full switches to change the language and it work as the flowing code

```
<?php
return [
'home_menu'=>'home',
'about_menu'=>'about',
'contact_menu'=>'contact',
'message'=>'<h1> welcoome</h1>',
];
```

Now I need to show text from contact.blade.php from resource/views Instead of
 `welcoome`.

Comment: You should learn about Laravel routing first.

Comment: please your gmail??

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can show your translations in Laravel

```php
    {{ trans(filename.arrayIndex) }}
    @lang(filename.arrayIndex)
```

and in case you have html in your translations then

```php
    {!! trans(filename.arrayIndex) !!}
```

I hope this will help you but you must check all the Laravel documentation before starting the project. It will really help you understanding the Lara Concept better

Comment: please your gmail??/